# How can I quickly add many markers to MapFragment in Google Map API v2 without locking UI thread?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, supportmapfragment

I am using the `Google Map API v2` and displaying markers on a map in a MapFragment.

I need to add many markers to the map quickly, but without locking the UI thread. There are 2 approaches I've tried, but either it takes a long time to add lots of markers or the UI thread freezes while drawing all the markers. Is there a different way to do this that works better?

Approach #1 (Adds them quickly, but locks UI thread until they are all added):

```
public void addMarkersFast(List<MarkerThing> thingsToShow) {
    if (getMap() == null) return; // Will be null for any device without google play services installed

    for (MarkerThing thing : thingsToShow) {
        getMap().addMarker(createMarker(thing));
    }
}
```

Approach #2 (Starts displaying immediately, but can take 20-30 seconds to add all the markers):

```
public void addMarkersSlow(final MarkerThingArray thingsToShow) {
    if (getMap() == null) return; // Will be null for any device without google play services installed

    MarkerThing thing = thingsToShow.get(i);
    getMap().addMarker(createMarker(thing));
    (new Handler()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {    // give some time for main thread to draw
        @Override
        public void run() {
            addMarkersSlow(thingsToShow, i + 1);
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

How can I do this differently to show all the markers in a 2k+ marker scenario without locking the UI thread for 3-4 seconds like approach #1 and without taking 30 seconds to gradually add them like approach #2?

Comment: are you only adding markers to the visible region on the map?

Comment: Yep, I strip out everything with a lat/long outside of the visible map boundaries before doing either of these approaches.

Comment: It might help to create a `map` reference and only call `getMap()` one time, instead of potentially calling it over 2000 times.

Answer (score 2):

2k+ markers on a single visible map region is a lot of subviews and objects to manage and draw, not to mention some potential usability issues.

Check out marker clustering:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

this allows you to "cluster" nearby markers into a collapsed marker.  You should attempt to get your overall number of markers/subviews down into the dozens.  Anyhow, a technique like this should help.

Comment: I agree completely with your comment about usability issues and and it not being an ideal approach. The general use case is 5-10, but the client wanted the extreme scenario to work as well so was looking into possibilities. I'll look into clustering, thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can write an AsynTask and publish the markers in the onProgress. I'm not a big fan of using AsyncTasks though, so I would do it using RxJava (with RxAndroid for Android specific schedulers).

Example:

```
Observable.just(thingsToShow)
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
    .map(new Func1<MarkerThing, Marker>() {
        @Override
        public Marker call(MarkerThing thing) {
            return createMarker(thing);
        }
    })
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Marker>() {
        @Override
        public void onNext(Marker marker) {
            getMap().addMarker(marker);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCompleted() {
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable e) { }
    });
```